# Forge viewer displays elements blurry in 2D views and the Measure extension does not work on them

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit

For some of our Revit models, in Forge viewer, 2D views are display blurry, no element can be selected and the **Measure** extension does not work on elements and only works on the dimensions and the titleblock.
Like this example:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAubE.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1272.png)

But it should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5km2.png)

I have tested it with our viewer, **A360** viewer and **Autodesk Forge Tools** vscode extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is because 2D drawings or PDFs can contain both **vector** graphics and **raster** graphics (this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-vs-raster-graphics) explains the difference between the two). The measure extension needs **vector** graphics in order to work properly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In both picture I've sent, the cursor was on a **Wall** Revit element, but in the first model, forge treats it as a raster graphic and in the second as a vector graphic.
In fact, in the second model all the elements are shown correctly as vector.
But this does not happen in the first model. I mean I can get a **Wall** dimensions in a 3D view, but in the 2D view it changed all elements to raster. Do you know how I can avoid it?

Comment: That I don't know :( Perhaps it's a matter of some Publish Settings on the Revit side?

Comment: Yaeh it was the case. I changed the **Model Display Style** to **Hidden Line** instead of **Shaded** in Revit, and the problem was solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice, you found it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Petr Broz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1759915/petr-broz) and his hint, by changing the **Model Display Style** in Revit side to **Hidden Line** instead of **Shaded** the problem was solved.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5IZf.png).

**Update:**

The **Shadows** in **Graphic Display Options**, also should be unchecked. [image]